# How to implement Autocloseable for resource opened on construction

Tags: java, autocloseable

I am have a resource I open on construction of my object. I use it to write throughout the lifetime of the object.  But my application can close without warning and I need to capture this.  The class is pretty straightforward.

```
public class SomeWriter {
    private Metrics metrics;

    public SomeWriter() {
        try (metrics = new Metrics()) { // I know I can't but the idea is there
        }
    }

    public void write(String blah) {
       metrics.write(blah);
    }

    public void close() {
       metrics.close();
    }
```

So, you get the idea.  I'd like to "Autoclose" Metrics if the application goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with the try-with-resource concept, which is for local scope only. The way you close the `Metrics` within your `close()` is the best you can do.

You best bet is to have `SomeWriter` also implement `AutoCloseable` and use the writer itself in the try-with-resources block, as in

```
try (SomeWriter writer = new SomeWriter()) {
}
// here, the Metrics will also have been closed.
```